# HVM virtualization with PV drivers on XenServer

Tags: xenserver

Is it possible to create an HVM guest in XenServer 5.5 that uses PV drivers for disk and network without being fully paravirutalized? This should give me decent performance from the VM without having to jump through hoops to create a PV guest when a pre-built template doesn't exist.

Since PV drivers exist for Windows, and XenServer provides templates for windows that use HVM virtualization this must be possible, I just don't see how to configure this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Just install the Citrix supplied XenTools that are included with your XenServer installation.  These drivers are paravirtualised drivers that install into your HVM Windows VM instance to improve the speed of network and disk IO.